# I can not figure out why am i getting the result 2

Tags: java, math

Maybe I'm missing out but I can't figure out why I am getting the result 2 in this code:

```
i = 1;
i = i-- - --i;
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: That's correct, what are you expecting?

Comment: I have seen this in some java question. But in real live it is strongly very-very bad practice to do so. It is much better to write more simplier to be understandable for everyone.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? You *are* decrementing `i` twice. And you shouldn't  ever do this.

Comment: 1 - (-1) = 2 ...

Comment: I am expecting the number one. --i = 0 so 1 - 0 will be one.

Comment: @Antonio Java strictly evaluates left to right, so no, `--i` is `-1`, because `i--` already happened first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216118/how-is-that-x-20x-x-x-x-final-value-of-x-in-java-is-65

Comment: Don't write unreadable code like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one should write code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `i = i-- - --i` you have:

- `i--`, a *post-decrement*, which retrieves the current value of `i` (`1`) and then decrements `i` to `0`
- `-`
- `--i`, a *pre-decrement*, which decrements `i` again and retrieves the updated value, `-1`

So you end up with `i = 1 - -1` which is `2`.

---

Needless to say, this sort of thing shows up on (silly) Java tests and such, but should never appear in production code.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch this, thank you for the help.